# Show $f'(\beta) \int\limits_\beta^\alpha 1 dt \leq \int\limits_\beta^\alpha f'(t) dt \leq f'(\alpha) \int\limits_\beta^\alpha 1 dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Assuming $f(x)$ is a function of single variable, and $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing

Then claim:
$f'(\beta) \int\limits_\beta^\alpha 1 dt \leq \int\limits_\beta^\alpha f'(t) dt \leq f'(\alpha) \int\limits_\beta^\alpha 1 dt$

How do you show this is true?

Attempt:

$\int\limits_\beta^\alpha f'(t) dt \leq f'(\alpha) \int\limits_\beta^\alpha 1 dt$ is equivalent to $f(\alpha) - f(\beta) \leq f'(\alpha)(\alpha - \beta)$

Which theorem guarantees that this is true?

Comment: That is not true unless you mean that $f'$ is monotonically increasing. A simple counter-example is $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $[1,2]$. btw the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) is the theorem you are looking for (and to use it to show what you want you need $f'(x) \leq f'(\alpha)$ for all $\beta \leq x \leq \alpha$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to use the mean value theorem. Also, the derivatives are just confusing (and so is the interval $[\beta,\alpha]$), so let me reformulate the statement as:

> Given $g$ monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$, show that
>   $$
> g(a)\int_a^b1\,dt\leq \int_a^b g(t)\,dt\leq g(b)\int_a^b1\,dt.
> $$

Let us look at the left inequality. Since $g(t)\geq g(a)$ for all $t\in[a,b]$, $g(t)-g(a)\geq 0$, and the integral of a non-negative function is non-negative (this follows by definition, since no undersums/Riemann sums can give negative contribution), i.e.
$$
\int_a^b g(t)-g(a)\,dt\geq 0.
$$
Next, by linearity of the integral, the above is equivalent to
$$
\int_a^b g(t)\,dt-g(a)\int_a^b 1\,dt\geq 0.
$$
Moving the things around, we get
$$
g(a)\int_a^b 1\,dt\leq \int_a^b g(t)\,dt.
$$
I leave it to you to show the second inequality in the same manners.